# How do you find a string in json.net that has mutiple values

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I have json file that has

```
[{"a":"Value","b":"Value"},{"a":"Value1","b":"Value1"}]
```

I want to find the "a" of Value1 how can I do this?
(Im not sure if this was asked before however i dont exactly know how to prase the sentence.

Comment: I dont think that is the actual content.  It doesnt look valid

Comment: i got it from http://maple.fm/api/list/items

Comment: now, **thats** valid JSON.  you made it invalid when you obfuscated and shrunk it down.

Comment: edited it, now its valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear because the answer will always be "a".  Look at the actual data:

> [{"a":"3010828","b":"Jupiter Chair"},{"a":"3010829","b":"Saturn Chair"}...]

A and B might be better named "ID" and "Item": ID "3010828" is "Jupiter Chair".

This is will convert the AB pairs into a Dictionary which will be a more useful way to step thru it.  When messing with these, it helps to see the internal structure.  Paste the JSON into a helper like http://jsonutils.com/  From there, we get this:

```
Public Class AB
    Public Property a As String
    Public Property b As String
End Class
```

It will deserialize easily into an Array or List.  The Array is not very interesting because it still has A and B glued together.  This will use a List of the above class and convert to a Dictionary to make it easy to find by ID:

```
Dim json As String = ' the long file

Dim jl As List(Of AB)
jl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of AB))(jstr)

Dim myCol As Dictionary(Of String, String) = jl.ToDictionary(
            Function(k) k.a,
            Function(k) k.b)

Console.WriteLine(myCol("5000074"))
```

Output:

> Bing Monkey

The List(Of AB) is perfectly usable, converting to a Dictionary makes it easier to get Items from the ID.  If you *really* want to fetch ID by the Item or Name, reverse `k.a` and `k.b` above.  And if you really only want one of the 43,000+ items, see the other answer.

---

> if i reverse k.a and k.b nothing happens ( i want the item id from item name)

It is probably throwing an exception you are not catching.  If you look deeper into the list you will see that there can be multiple IDs for certain Items.  That would be illegal in a Dictionary, and makes it pointless to try and create a searchable container.

Instead, leave it as a `List(Of AB)` and query it to find stuff:

```
Dim findTxt As String = "Miho"
' get a list of all IDs (A) where B matches the above, case insensitive:
Dim miho = jl.Where(Function(x) x.b.ToLowerInvariant = 
      findTxt.ToLowerInvariant).Select(Function(m) m.a).ToList

' get all matches as into smaller List(of AB)
Dim AllMihoAB = jl.Where(Function(x) x.b.ToLowerInvariant =
                                      findTxt.ToLowerInvariant).ToList

' get just the first ID to match:
Dim FirstMihoA = jl.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.b.ToLowerInvariant =
             findTxt.ToLowerInvariant).a
```

I have no idea how you want to use it.

Comment: Your code worked, but if i reverse k.a and k.b ( i want the item id from item name) nothing happens.

Comment: I was suspecting that.

Comment: I guess you do not really have to swap A and B since it wont act like a dictionary anyway (I was trying to get it into a searchable container for you).  Likewise, since it is simple enough, you can also just use the `List(of AB)` and use LINQ to query it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but I think you meant that you want to find a specific object in the JSON array where the `a` property has the value `Value1`.  In that case you can use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html) (JObjects, etc.) to find it like this:

```
Dim json As String = _
    "[{""a"":""Value"",""b"":""Value""},{""a"":""Value1"",""b"":""Value1""}]"

Dim array As JArray = JArray.Parse(json)

Dim obj As JObject = _ 
    array.FirstOrDefault(Function(jo As JObject) jo("a").ToString() = "Value1")

If obj Is Nothing Then
    Console.WriteLine("Not found")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("a: " & obj("a").ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("b: " & obj("b").ToString())
End If
```